# Update Tableview's footerview uilabel value

Tags: ios

I am having uiviewcontroller which is loading the UIView as a subview with tableview.
I have set footerview which is having the label which value are change base on the API response.
I have onde dropdown menu on button click. and from didselectrowatindexpath i will change the value of tableview footer label value.
after get response of json i have to change the value. so for that i had use Perfomselector withdelay and call one method which will change the value.
also i am declare uilabel in .h file which is set in footer.
I had try but i don't know what is my mistake.
here is my code
**From DropDown menu - didselectrowatindexpath**

```
[[singletone sharedManager] getCartItems:ca.TotlaAmt];
[self performSelector:@selector(doneCart) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
```

```
-(void)doneCart
{
    [ca setTextToAmount:TotalAmount];
}
```

**In UIVIew Call the method For change footer lable value**

```
-(void)setTextToAmount : (NSString *)amt
{
    FooterLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rs %@",TotalAmount];
}
```

but this is not working. TotalAmount is the Value which is get from json response. 
how to solve this?

Comment: What is the use of 'amt' in `(NSString *)amt`?

Comment: here is nothing, i have write before while i am testing. so ignore it

Comment: "In UIVIew Call " - calling in UIView? And what is `"ca"`?

Comment: ca is my Custom UIView which is added in Main ViewController. and ys it's calling in uiview.